# Finding $x + y$ from two equations given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $x^2 + xy + y^2 = 132$ and $x + \sqrt{xy}+ y = 33$ then $x + y = ?$

I'm trying to figure out why the solution is $37/2$.

When I convert the first equation to $(x+y)^2 + xy = 132$, I get the output of $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = 132 - xy$ but the solution set shows that it's $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = 132 + xy$. Why is the right side "xy" positive? It should be negative???

Comment: $x^2 + xy + y^2 \ne (x+y)^2 + xy$.  And $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy +y^2$ we have $x^2 + xy +y^2 = (x+y)^2 - xy$.

Comment: "When I convert the first equation to $(x+y)^2 + xy = 132$,".  This is wrong.  It should be : $(x+y)^2 - xy = 132$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2 + y^2 \ne (x+y)^2$ and $x^2 + xy +y^2 \ne (x+y)^2 + xy$.

As $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ we instead have $x^2 + xy + y^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - xy = (x+y)^2 -xy$

So $x^2 + 2xy +y^2 = 132 +xy$.

Which we could have gotten for them the start by simply adding $xy$ to each side:  $x^2 + xy +y^2 = 132$ so $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = 132 + y^2$.

Any how $(x+y)^2 = 132 +xy$.

Meanwhile $x + y + \sqrt{xy} = 33$ so $\sqrt{xy} = 33-(x+y)$ and so

Anyway so $(x+y)^2 = 132 + xy$ and $x+y = 33-\sqrt{xy}$.

Let $x+y = M$ we have $M^2 - 132 = xy$ and $M -33 = -\sqrt{xy}$.  Squaring the latter gives us $(M-33)^2 = xy$ so

$M^2 - 132 = (M-33)^2$ which we can just solve.

Comment: This was a massive help. I thought by combining x^2 + y^2 would equal to (x+y)^2. Clearly not but the solution simply added a xy on both side.

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}(x+y)^2&=x^2+2xy+y^2\\&=132+xy\\&=132+\sqrt{xy}^2\\&=132+\bigl(33-(x+y)\bigr)^2\end{align}and that the only solution of the equation $z^2=132-(33-z)^2$ is $\frac{37}2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was saying that $x^2+xy+y^2 = (x+y)^2+xy$. This is because $x^2 +y^2 \ne (x+y)^2$. If you multiply out $(x+y)^2$, you get $(x+y)(x+y) = x(x+y) + y(x+y) =x^2 + xy + yx +y^2 = x^2 +2xy +y^2$.

So, $x^2+xy+y^2=132$, which means $x^2+2xy+y^2 = 132+xy$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$(33 - x - y)^2 = (\sqrt {xy})^2$

$x^2+xy+y^2 - 66(x+y) + 1089 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Try squaring the second equation and make use of the given values.

$\begin{align}&\left(x^2+y^2+xy\right)+2(\sqrt{xy}(x+y)+xy) = 33^2 \\
\Rightarrow&\left(x^2+y^2+xy\right)+2\sqrt{xy}(x+y+\sqrt{xy}) = 33^2\\
\Rightarrow&(132)+2\sqrt{xy}(33) = 33^2\Rightarrow \boxed{\sqrt{xy} = \frac{29}{2}}\end{align}$

So, $\boxed{x+y = 33 - \sqrt{xy} = 33- \frac{29}{2} = \frac{37}{2}} $

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt x=a,\sqrt y=b$

We have  $$a^2+ab+b^2=33\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$132=\cdots=(a^2+b^2)^2-(ab)^2=(a^2+ab+b^2)(a^2-ab+b^2)\ \ \ \ (2)$$

$$\implies a^2-ab+b^2=\dfrac{132}{33}=?\ \ \ \ (3)$$

$(1)+(3)=?$

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering that this solution hasn't appeared yet. So, I add it.

$$x^2+xy+y^2 = (x+y)^2 - xy $$$$= \underbrace{(x+y+\sqrt{xy})}_{=33}(x+y-\sqrt{xy})=132$$

Hence,

$$x+y-\sqrt{xy} =\frac{132}{33}=4$$

So,
$$2(x+y) = (x+y+\sqrt{xy}) + (x+y-\sqrt{xy})=33+4=37 $$ $$\Rightarrow x+y=\frac{37}{2}$$